# How to parse timezone ID's in Dart?

Tags: dart

How do I parse a timezone ID such as `America/New_York` into `UTC-5` or `Europe/Helsinki` into `UTC+2`?

Even better if the DST is taken into account (so in previous 2 examples, both have DST right now).

I'm trying to parse this into a date time object:

```
America/New_York:20130208T080000
```

The last part of the string is easy, can be parsed with either using a custom date format or simply `DateTime.parse()`, but I have no found a way to parse the timezone ID.

Also, I need to do this on the server side. I'm downloading and parsing iCal feeds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the unix [date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_%28Unix%29) command :

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  Process.run('date', ['+%z'],  environment: {"TZ":":Europe/Helsinki"})
    .then((e){
      print(e.stdout); // display +0300
    });
}
```

Comment: Ha. Won't work on Windows but I guess that's fine for now since the production is on SUSE. I'll wait a few days to see if anyone comes with a better solution. :)

Comment: This isn't very cool solution, because I easily run out of "open files".. :/

Comment: You can perhaps use a cache. The returned value should not change so often.

Comment: That's indeed what I happened to do for now. I just need to be careful about DST changes.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database, it looks like (from some limited research), that you can download the timezoneDB from here:  http://timezonedb.com/download
in CSV or SQL format.

I'd reckon that the next step could to be to code-gen a Dart library to hard-code the name-to-UTC conversion from the CSV/SQL data (or dynamically load the data as required).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in the SDK that has that information built into it, so you'd need to either import it into your own program or use something external that can parse it, as in the previous examples.